# Remove variable from URL

Tags: php

This is for a simple login system, any time a user receives an error I redirect them to a another page (using header(Location:...)) and put the error ID in the URL so that I know which error to display.

**login.php**

```html
<?php
if(isset($_GET[ 'status'])){
  if($_GET[ 'status']=='error' ){ 
?>
<p style='color:red;'>Incorrect Username/Password combination!</p>
<?php 
} }
?>
```

**Checklog.php**

```html
<?php
include('../dbconnect.php');

$username =$_POST['form-username'];
$pwd =$_POST['form-password'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE email='$username' and password='$pwd'") or die ('Query failed:'.mysql_error());
//$admin=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where user='$username' and code='$pwd'") or die ('Query failed:'.mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user']=$username;
//echo "hello $username";
    header("Location:../homepage.html");
}
/*else if (mysql_num_rows($admin)>0){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['admin']=007;
    header("Location:add1.php");
}*/
else
{
    header("Location:login.php?status=error");
}

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

On refresh the error message is still here, is there a solution how i can redirect the user to the original login.php without the error message if he refresh

Comment: To do it on refresh you would have to somehow save that he has already viewed it once. So you could set a session or update a database table that says that error has already been viewed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript `window.history.pushState` to alter the URL after the document has fully loaded. This will change the URL in the address bar and affects the address they are taken to on refresh.

Alternatively you can store messages in the `$_SESSION` and clear the message after it has been displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with henrys answer. Personally id use $_SESSIONS but as as your question was to remove url parameters the only way would be js.

For example

```
history.pushState(null,null, window.location.href.split('?')[0]);
```

This is untested but should do what you want in a single line of code.